# catkin_make toplevel.cmake in Yocto

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am trying to install ROS into an embedded device (imx8m-mini variscite dart) using Yocto. I have added required ROS packages into the Yocto environment and generated a root file system. I have sourced the **setup.bash** script in my bash environment and then when I do "**catkin_make**" I get an error like this,

```
 **Creating the toplevel cmake file failed: Could neither find file "toplevel.cmake" in any workspace nor relative, checked the following paths:**
/home/root/catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake 
/opt/ros/melodic/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
```

As a result, the directories  **build, devel, and src** are empty.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371127/catkin_make-toplevel.cmake-in-yocto/) by [ogd](https://answers.ros.org/users/69380/ogd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved after adding below package into Yocto build

> catkin-dev

---

Originally posted by [ogd](https://answers.ros.org/users/69380/ogd/) with karma: 26 on 2021-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0